# custom font lobster not working in IE

Tags: html, css, fonts

I want to user the custom font lobster.I have downloaded `lobster.woff2` file and placed it in font folder.
In my custom css I have add as

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'Lobster';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Lobster'), local('Lobster-Regular'),
  url(./fonts/lobster.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215; 
}

.wishes,{
    color: #ff6315;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive !important;
 }
```

This is working in chrome and firefox but not in IE

Comment: Do you have a url, and what version of IE are you testing in? Vital information so we can help you with the problem. Woff2 format is only available in Edge, and no IE before that supports it, so you'll need to provide the other versions - I recommend adding it to your html rather than @importing it to your stylesheet.

Comment: i'm using IE12.testing in localhost so having no url

Comment: I recommend using the header html url to load the font to your page instead of @importing it.

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use google font API instead... It will fix your IE issue.

- **Google Chrome:** version 4.249.4+
- **Mozilla Firefox:** version: 3.5+
- **Apple Safari:** version 3.1+
- **Opera:** version 10.5+
- **Microsoft Internet Explorer:** version 6+

---

Your code should be:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster');

.wishes {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
```

Comment: Why not use the html header link to the font instead?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to add the link to the google font in the head of your html, then call it in your stylesheet as normal. This code from [here](https://fonts.google.com/?query=lobster&selection.family=Lobster) and you paste this snippet in the head of your html:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
```

To use the font in your stylesheet do this, make sure to provide a relevant fallback:

```
font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
```